# How to stop automatic gc() in R?

Tags: r, garbage-collection

While analysing a function that i wrote in R using profvis({}) i noticed that a lot of time is consumed by the GC (see the figure)

[image]

This is an automatic GC (i did not put the command in the code), and i am sure to have a lot of free RAM memory , so this is just a waste of time. 
Is there any way to stop this? I call this function thousand of times, so each second is important.
Any other help is welcome

Comment: How did you get this visualization with the time each process took?

Comment: I used the function profvis({ *MY_CODE*})

Comment: Read `help("Memory")`. Anyway, I suspect you are trying to optimize the wrong thing. Messing with garbage collection is not something I'd do. If you call a function thousands of times, you should usually use Rcpp to implement it.

Comment: Thank you roland, the Memory documentation has been very useful.
Rewrite the whole function (thousand of line codes) is out of question: i didn't write this code, they just told me to check if it is possibile to speed up the computation with the minimum effort